# What is the simplest way to covert this

Tags: mysql, sql, select

What would be the fastest way to turn something like this

```
╔════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║ IMG1  ║ IMG2  ║ IMG3  ║
╠════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║ 1.jpg ║ 2.jpg ║ 3.jpg ║
║  2 ║ 1.jpg ║ 2.jpg ║ 3.jpg ║
║  3 ║ 1.jpg ║ 2.jpg ║ 3.jpg ║
╚════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

Into this

```
╔════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ IMAGES ║
╠════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ 1.jpg  ║
║  1 ║ 2.jpg  ║
║  1 ║ 3.jpg  ║
║  2 ║ 1.jpg  ║
║  2 ║ 2.jpg  ║
║  2 ║ 3.jpg  ║
║  3 ║ 1.jpg  ║
║  3 ║ 2.jpg  ║
║  3 ║ 3.jpg  ║
╚════╩════════╝
```

Answer (score 3):

use `UNION ALL`. `ALL` is define if you want to keep duplicate records. But if you want unique records, remove the `ALL`.

```
SELECT id, img1 as images FROM tableNAME
UNION ALL
SELECT id, img2 as images FROM tableNAME
UNION ALL
SELECT id, img3 as images FROM tableNAME
-- ORDER BY ID, images
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56dc3/1)